# Best practices for runtime-only dependencies in OSGi

Tags: java, osgi, dependency-management, loose-coupling, osgi-fragment

In line with the [Open-Closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle), I typically design my Java packages and libraries in such a way that there is a generic "interface" or "API" package/library and one or more implementations (quite similar to many common APIs like JDBC or JAXP/SAX).
To locate an implementation (or sometimes multiple implementations) in the base API library without violating OCP, I commonly use Java's [ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) mechanism, or occasionally classpath scanning via third-party libraries like [ClassGraph](https://github.com/classgraph/classgraph#classgraph) or [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections#java-runtime-metadata-analysis-in-the-spirit-of-scannotations). From a Maven perspective, the implementations are brought in as `runtime` dependencies (as they're only needed at execution time, but not at compile time). Pretty standard stuff.

So, now, I want to make some of these packages available as OSGi bundles (with API and implementation in separate bundles), but since in OSGi each bundle has its own class loader, neither classpath scanning nor the `ServiceLoader` API will work for this purpose. At first glance, OSGi's "fragment" mechanism seems to be the closest equivalent to the plain-Java setup described above. In that scenario, the API bundle would be the "fragment host", and concrete implementations would attach as fragments to that host bundle. As the fragment host and all its attached fragments use the same class loader, the standard plain-Java mechanisms like `ServiceLoader` or ClassGraph would conceivably still work. This would also have the advantage that there would be no need to detect whether a library/bundle is running in an OSGi context or not, and no OSGi framework dependencies are needed.

So, in a nutshell, my question is: are fragments the correct way to implement runtime-only dependencies in OSGi or is there a better (or more standard) way? Preferably, I'm looking for a solution that works in an OSGi container but does not require a dependency on OSGi itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No Fragments are almost *always* wrong outside the translations. The OSGi model is to use *services*.

The way to go then is to use DS. Using bnd (in maven, gradle, ant, sbt, or Bndtools) you can create *components*. A component is a Plain Old Java Object (POJO) that is annotated with injection and activation instructions. You could make those components to take all its dependencies in the constructor.

The bnd code uses the annotations to generate an XML file that is used in runtime to create, activate, inject, and register those components. This will then work out of the box in an OSGi Framework. The annotations are build time so they do not create dependencies in your runtime.

In your non-OSGi environment, you'd be responsible to call that constructor yourself. So you gather your dependencies using the Service Loader and then construct them in the right order.

```
@Component
public class MyComponent implements Foo {

      final Bar bar;

      @Activate
      public MyComponent( @Reference Bar bar ) {
        this.bar = bar;
      }
      ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, @PeterKriens. I had completely forgotten about OSGi's Declarative Services. Your suggested solution would require adding at least a dependency on `org.osgi.service.component.annotations`, but that's probably an acceptable trade-off (though I had hoped to do something more like the bundles in Eclipse's Orbit repository, i.e. JARs with an OSGi manifest, that are otherwise identical to their non-OSGi counterparts).

Comment: Before I accept this answer, would you mind clarifying why fragments "are almost always wrong outside the translations"? My understanding is that fragments are intended for "extensions" of existing bundles. For example, one of my intended use cases is a base/API bundle with an inefficient default implementation, and an extension bundle that provides a more efficient solution (that is also more heavy-weight in terms of dependencies, so not everyone might choose that option). Are translations/I18N really the only legitimate use of fragments? What are the downsides of incorrect use of fragments?

Comment: Fragments are the siren songs for people that grew up in the classloader mud of standard java. They provide a recognizable environment but also kill the strong modularity of OSGi. I.e. is trying to eat your cake and have it too. Sometimes it works, but in general I see so much misery with them because they open up the fences where the rest of the system desperately tries to keep them closed. There are some uses but since they are never really needed, start without them.